# libGDX camera zoom is different on different devices:

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm making a game on both desktop and android and the same code results in two different screens (cam.zoom is the same in both):
[image: Left is my desktop and right is an android device]

The desired result is the left screen and the code used to render is like so: (the image is 8000x4000 and is a place holder for my map)

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {
    private final Application application;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private ShapeRenderer sr;
    private OrthographicCamera cam;
    private Viewport viewport;

    private Button startGame;
    private Texture background = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("background.jpg"));

    public MainMenuScreen(final Application application) {
        this.application = application;
        cam = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        viewport = new FitViewport(WIDTH, HEIGHT, cam);

        batch = this.application.batch;
        sr = this.application.sr;

        startGame = new Button(-50, -25, 100, 50);
        startGame.setColour(new Color(0.01f, 0.35f, 0.47f, 1));
        startGame.setText("Start game", this.application.font);
        startGame.setHasBorder(true);
        startGame.setBorderThickness(3);
        startGame.setBorderColour(new Color(0.02f, 0.62f, 0.79f, 1));
        startGame.setTextColour(new Color(0.02f, 0.62f, 0.79f, 1));

    }

    public void update() {
        Vector2 mousePos = Extras.getMousePos(viewport);
        if (startGame.isClickedOn(mousePos)) {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        ScreenUtils.clear(0, 0, 0, 1);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
        sr.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

        update();
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(background, -background.getWidth() / 2, -background.getHeight() / 2);
        batch.end();
        startGame.render(this.sr, this.batch);
    }
```

How do I make sure all different devices have the same zoom in the camera?
A possible solution I don't know how to implement yet could be setting cam.zoom to a value dependent on the screen size somehow but there has to be a better way for this using libGDX itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, are you trying to make the button size's same on all device's screen resolution? or you want to make camera zooming have same value?

Ok, How the variable **WIDTH** and **HEIGHT** was declared?
if you have declared both with one spesific size. Its will be not same if you're trying in another resolutions.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
//Constant Spesific Value of WIDTH and HEIGHT Size.
public static final int WIDTH = 1280, HEIGHT = 720;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

//Non-Constant Value of WIDTH and HEIGHT Size.
public static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
...

//Define Both In Main.class
public MainGameScreen(){
  WIDTH = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
  HEIGHT = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
}
```

However, **LibGDX's** screen resolution can be calculated. Some object size in your game must be spesific, when calculating the size between both **WIDTH** and **HEIGHT** you need to know, how the size will be same in all device with one spesific calculation.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
/* Button (256x72) in Screen Resolution (1280x720)
   Button (160x48) in Screen Resolution (800x480) */

startGame = new Button(0,0, WIDTH/5, HEIGHT/10);

//Button (400x100) in All Screen (Constant Value)

startGame = new Button(0,0, 400, 100);
```

So, i suggest you to make a calculation to sizing some objects in your game. Because its will be different if you trying to make value in constant.

Ok, the next is, **OrthographicCamera**
 Which you want to make same value of zoom right? the cam.zoom is a floating value. Its not a constant value, but it was a  variable value that can be changed in all time.

You can trying this code, if you want to zoom camera directly on game

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
  //Zoom Out
  cam.zoom += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
  //Zoom In
  cam.zoom -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
}
```

Or if you talking about static-zoom, in a spesific value (not directly changed)

```
cam.zoom = 1f; //for 1 value of Zoom Out
```

I hope you understand what i means and im sorry if my answers can't be helpful for you, cause im still learning too, all about LibGDX.

Comment: I declared WIDTH and HEIGHT using `Gdx.graphics.getXXX()`. Isn't that what gets the device size? And yes it is the zoom that I want to modify, not the actual size of the button

Comment: The sizing works when I do it relevant to the screens size, thank you! But I still don't understand what you said about cam.zoom. I know it isn't constant but what I meant was that I dont know how to make the zoom be the same amount on different devices.

Comment: You can try to debuging the cam.zoom value into Label, BitmapFont or something good, that you can see what happens while running your game. I means that you need to compare both screen zoom value with **Displayed Text**. Example using `label.setText(String.format("ZOOM-VALUE: %d",(int) cam.zoom));`

Comment: I have tried but heres the problem: the cam.zoom value is the same in both images you see in the question. It seems the device type is having an influence

Answer (score 0):

@Alf Equilfe was the one who helped me get to it with his answer and here is the actual solution:

Set WIDTH, HEIGHT to a constant value independent of device size (make it so that any device can handle the size, in my case i chose 1024, 512) and make the aspect ratio the scale so it looks same on all devices.